# How can I calculate the sum of all positive integers less than n?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following function:

```
f(n) = f(n - 1) + (n - 1)
f(0) = 0
n >= 0
```

I have `n` declared on column A, and need the result of `f(n)` on column B.

I'm trying to find the Excel formula equivalent for this function.

Sample Result:

```
A | B
--+--
0 | 0
```

or:

```
A | B
--+--
1 | 0
```

or:

```
A | B
--+--
4 | 6
```

**but never**:

```
A | B
--+--
0 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 1
...
```

The biggest problem is, I can't simulate the value of `f(n - 1)`. So referencing the previous row like the above example is invalid. I'm almost sure the answer is trivial, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does this help?

```
f(n) = sum of all positive integers less than n
```

It should, especially with the help of [some arithmetic](http://www.cs.ecu.edu/~hochberg/fall2002/class10/fslide1.html).

OK, given that [people are now posting answers with user defined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225059/how-can-i-calculate-the-sum-of-all-positive-integers-less-than-n/1225090#1225090), here is the answer

```
f(n) = (n-1)n/2
```

**Update**: For those who cannot see that the formula does not use any information from any other rows (see Stan R.'s comment below), I jumbled up the order a little bit:

```
 0  =(A1-1)*A1/2    0
 9  =(A2-1)*A2/2    36
 2  =(A3-1)*A3/2    1
 4  =(A4-1)*A4/2    6
 6  =(A5-1)*A5/2    15
 5  =(A6-1)*A6/2    10
10  =(A7-1)*A7/2    45
 8  =(A8-1)*A8/2    28
 3  =(A9-1)*A9/2    3
 7  =(A10-1)*A10/2  21
 1  =(A11-1)*A11/2  0
...
```

Comment: presumably f is just a stand in for a more complex recusive function

Comment: @Scott Weinstein The question is the question. If am going to get downvoted for answering the question as it was posted, so be it.

Comment: assuming that column A is going to be sequential then your example works.

Comment: Scott, the question doesn't imply that at all. If the question is intended to mean, "How can I perform a general recursive function in Excel?" than, well, that's what the question should say. The less snarky version of Sinan's (completely correct) answer is: f(n + 1) = (n^2 + n)/2

Comment: good points, perhaps less presumption on my part...

Comment: @WCWedin OK, I did get a little snarky. At first, I thought simply showing the formula would accomplish the required hand to forehead motion and that would have been it. Once programmers, not lay people, start posting user defined functions for a well known arithmetic formula, methinks it's time to be a little snarky.

Comment: @Stan R What on earth do you mean by *sequential*. The only reason the numbers in the left-most column are sequential is convenience. I'll update that example for you.

Comment: @Sinan: my apologies sir, I didn't notice that its the (value-1) not (cell-1). I haven't dealt with Excel in a while..should stick with C# :D

Comment: ...ohhh and +1 :)

Comment: Right on Sinan, this is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Do you need to solve it recursively? That's certainly not the nicest way to solve it:

> Sum the numbers 1 to 10

```
   1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
+ 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6
  --  --  --  --  --
  11 +11 +11 +11 +11 = 55
```

or, as it's summarised, `(n+1)(n/2)` -- with n=10, this is obviously `11 x 5`

Comment: Doh!  Forgot about Gauss...

Comment: I should point out that I'm actually solving for (n+1) as it's phrased in the question, but the normal expression of this problem is summing to a number, *inclusive*

Answer (score 3):

The function can be restated to eliminate the recursion.

Let's take a couple of examples here...

```
f(4)=1+2+3=6
f(5)=1+2+3+4=10
f(6)=1+2+3+4+5=15
```

There's a pattern here:

```
f(4)=1+2+3=6=4*1.5
f(5)=1+2+3+4=10=5*2
f(6)=1+2+3+4+5=15=6*2.5
```

which means we can generalize the function to `f(n)=1+2+...+n=n*(n-1)/2` for n>1 and `f(n)=0` otherwise.

The resulting Excel formula can then be written as `=IF(A5>1;A5*(A5-1)/2);0)`, assuming A5 contains n.

Obviously, if your formula is more complex than the one you gave, it may become quite a bit harder, and it may be a lot quicker and easier to just write a user defined function like the one suggested by Scott and then use that.

Answer (score 3):

Excel has something called Array Formulas, which allows a function to return a set of values. You can read more about them [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx). These will effectively let you write, with some creativity, analogs to recursive algorithms. Array formulas must be entered in using **Shift-Ctrl-Enter**.

To answer your question, have an array function return *1* through *n-1*, and wrap it in a sum. Here, *Indirect* creates a reference, and *A1* holds *n*:

```
=SUM( ROW( INDIRECT("1:"&A1-1) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117146/sigma-summation-in-excel-for-accumulated-value/64122729#64122729). I was tearing my hair out trying to find a way to make {4,3,2,1} change when the cell value changed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it with pure formulas. One option is a UDF

```
Public Function f(n As Integer) As Integer
    If (n = 0) Then
        f = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (n > 0) Then
        f = f(n - 1) + (n - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

and then the formula is just `=f(A1)`

Comment: beat me with the code :P

Answer (score 0):

if understand you correctly then you are trying to create a recursive function and circular references in Excel are not allowed. Your best bet is to create your own worksheet function.

Press Alt+F11 to go into VB then Insert>Module
then follow [Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225059/how-can-i-calculate-the-sum-of-all-positive-integers-less-than-n/1225090#1225090) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the way that this is done is to define your own functions.  In the VBA editor, insert a new module into your workbook and paste in the following function:

```
Function f(n As Integer)
    If n <= 0 Then
        f = 0
    Else
        f = f(n - 1) + (n - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Now you can call this directly:

```
=f(A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(MOD(A1,2)=0,(A1-1)*ROUND(A1/2,0), (A1) * ((A1-1)/2))
```

I don't know, if that is what you are looking for.